# Pairing up arrays of different length in Python

Tags: python, loops, iterator, one-to-many, python-itertools

Given two arrays of different lengths:

```
Column_a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
Column_b = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j]
```

I would like to pair them up and provide a DataFrame, so that all the elements in Column_b are paired up with an element of Column_a:

```
print(df)
               Column_a  Column_b
               0         a
               1         b
               2         c
               3         d
               1         e
               2         f
               3         g
               0         h
               1         i
               2         j
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```py
from itertools import cycle

Column_a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
Column_b = 'abcdefghij'
df = zip(cycle(Column_a if len(Column_a) < len(Column_b) else Column_b),
         Column_b if len(Column_a) < len(Column_b) else Column_a)
print(list(df))
```

**Output:**

```
[(0, 'a'),
 (1, 'b'),
 (2, 'c'),
 (3, 'd'),
 (0, 'e'),
 (1, 'f'),
 (2, 'g'),
 (3, 'h'),
 (0, 'i'),
 (1, 'j')]
```

Note that a string value in Python can be used as an iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple for loop to iterate over the longest column and create a list of tuples containing each element x from it, assigned to the element [*index_of_x % length_shortest_column*].

For example:

```
df = []
for i,x in enumerate(column_b):
    df.append( (x, column_a[i % len(a)]) )
```

This should net you the following (assuming column_b holds chars):

```
df = [('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 3),
      ('e', 0), ('f', 1), ('g', 2), ('h', 3),
      ('i', 0), ('j', 1)]
```

You may want to use a different datastructure for df but the general idea is still the same. The only important bit is that you should iterate over the longest list. Maybe there is a nicer way to do it, but this should get you going if on a pinch.